# Why can't I return from recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

Alright Stackoverflow first post here. I am at a loss, and would appreciate any help.

I have a recursive function that seems to be working properly up until I try and return from it. (Just a little maze runner for fun)

When reaching the return statement it seems to loop back to the `if(grid[y+1][x] ===2)` statement.
Then I don't see the function getting called again, but the values for `y` and `x` start changing as it loops around the function before getting to the `else` at the bottom and returning there.

I also see the "inside return if" in the console, and setting break points in the browser shows the return statement gets called, just doesn't exit the function.

Many thanks in advance!!!

```
const grid =[0,0,0,0,3,2], 
            [0,0,0,0,3,0],
            [0,0,0,0,3,0],
            [3,3,3,3,3,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,3,3,3,3,3]
        ],

const recursiveSearch = (y, x) => { // init values y=5 x=0


    console.log(y + '  ' + x);
    if(grid[y-1]){
        if(grid[y-1][x] === 0) {
            grid[y-1][x] = 4;
            recursiveSearch(y-1, x);
        }
        if(grid[y-1][x] === 2) {
            console.log('inside return if');
            return 'end point found at';
        }
    }
    if(grid[y][x+1] || grid[y][x+1] === 0) {
        if(grid[y][x+1] === 0) {
            grid[y][x+1] = 4;
            recursiveSearch(y,x+1);
        }
        if(grid[y][x+1] === 2) {
            return "end point found at";
        }
    }
    if(grid[y+1] || grid[y+1] === 0) {
        if(grid[y+1][x] === 0) {
            grid[y+1][x] = 4;
            recursiveSearch(y+1,x);
        }
        if(grid[y+1][x] === 2) {
            return "end point found at";
        }
    }
    if(grid[y][x-1] || grid[y][x-1] === 0 ) {
        if(grid[y][x-1] === 0) {
            grid[y][x-1] = 4;
            recursiveSearch(y,x-1);
        };
        if(grid[y][x-1] === 2) {
            return "end point found at";
        }
    } else {
        return "No solution found"
    }
};
```

Comment: You're not returning anything when you recursively call `recursiveSearch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must return value of calling recursive function.

```js
const grid =[0,0,0,0,3,2], 
            [0,0,0,0,3,0],
            [0,0,0,0,3,0],
            [3,3,3,3,3,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,3,3,3,3,3]
        ],

const recursiveSearch = (y, x) => { // init values y=5 x=0


    console.log(y + '  ' + x);
    if(grid[y-1]){
        if(grid[y-1][x] === 0) {
            grid[y-1][x] = 4;
            return recursiveSearch(y-1, x); // must return value of calling recursiveSearch
        }
        if(grid[y-1][x] === 2) {
            console.log('inside return if');
            return 'end point found at';
        }
    }
    if(grid[y][x+1] || grid[y][x+1] === 0) {
        if(grid[y][x+1] === 0) {
            grid[y][x+1] = 4;
            return recursiveSearch(y,x+1); // // must return value of calling recursiveSearch
        }
        if(grid[y][x+1] === 2) {
            return "end point found at";
        }
    }
    if(grid[y+1] || grid[y+1] === 0) {
        if(grid[y+1][x] === 0) {
            grid[y+1][x] = 4;
            return recursiveSearch(y+1,x); // must return value of calling recursiveSearch
        }
        if(grid[y+1][x] === 2) {
            return "end point found at";
        }
    }
    if(grid[y][x-1] || grid[y][x-1] === 0 ) {
        if(grid[y][x-1] === 0) {
            grid[y][x-1] = 4;
            return recursiveSearch(y,x-1); // must return value of calling recursiveSearch
        };
        if(grid[y][x-1] === 2) {
            return "end point found at";
        }
    } else {
        return "No solution found"
    }
};
```

Comment: Some explanation of why this fixes the problem would make this a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add return statement for every recursive call.